# Cython: "Cannot convert Python object" error

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to get a test project working that calls a C function, with an array parameter, from Python:

**test.cpp**:

```
void testFn(int arr[]);

void testFn(int arr[])
{
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
}
```

**caller.pyx**:

```
import ctypes

cdef extern from "test.cpp":
    void testFn(int arr[])

def myTest():
    a = [0, 0]
    arr = a.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_integer))
    testFn(arr)
    print(arr)
```

**setup.caller.py**:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

sourcefiles = ['caller.pyx']
ext_modules = [Extension("caller", sourcefiles)]

setup(
    name = 'test app',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

But when I try to build the project I get an error:

```
$ python setup.caller.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning caller.pyx to caller.c

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
def myTest():
    a = [0, 0]
    arr = a.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_integer))
    testFn(arr)
          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

caller.pyx:13:11: Cannot convert Python object to 'int *'
```

Comment: You need to give `arr` a type. `cdef int* arr` should do the trick.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This question pops up so often, but I was not able to find a good duplicate-target, which would go beyond "just do that and it will work".

This is a very usual situation: you try to pass some python data structures to c-code which expects pointers `int *, double *,...`. However pointers are not a python object, so we cannot pass them from/to python code.

Cython can automatically handle conversion to `int`, `double`, `float` and so on, even `char *` (it is a null-terminated c-string) and some [stl-containers](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#standard-library), but not to pointers (`char *`being the one exception).

There are two most common situations:

1. the internal representation of the python-data is already a c-array (`array.array`, numpy-arrays).
2. the internal representation isn't a continuous array (e.g. `list`)

**1. Passing via memory-view:**

There is no way in python we can somehow get hold of a pointer, so this must be done in cython. My first choice to pass an `array.array` or `numpy.array` (or any other python-object supporting [buffer-protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html), for `ctypes.Array` see for example this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60611145/5769463)) to a cython-function would be a memory-view:

```
def myTest(int[:] arr):
    testFn(&arr[0])
```

and now calling it from python:

```
>>> import array
>>> a=array.array('i', [0]*2)
>>> import caller
>>> caller.myTest(a)
>>> a
array('i', [1, 2]) #it worked
```

The following is important

1. `int[:]` is a python object (a typed memory view) so it can be passed to a python function (`def` or `cpdef`).
2. `&arr[0]` is used to take the address of the buffer of the memory view. Its result is of type `int *`.
3. The call of the function is "type-safe", you cannot pass for example `array.array('I', [0]*2)` to it, because it is not a `int`-memory-view but a `unsigned int`-memory-view.

**2. Passing non-continuous memory (e.g. lists):**

There is more work with `list` and Co.: The information is not stored in plain c-arrays so we need to copy them first to a continuous memory, pass this temp variable to our c-code and copy the results back to list, our cython function could looks as follows

```
import array
def myTest2(lst):
    tmp=array.array('i', lst)
    myTest(tmp)
    lst.clear()
    lst.extend(tmp)
```

And now after reloading the `caller` module:

```
>>> lst=[0,0]
>>> caller.myTest2(lst)
[1, 2]
```

So, it is possible to pass the content of a list to a c-function, but basically you want to work with `array.array` or `numpy.array` if you need data-exchange with c-code.