# How to direcly access the pointer of a Python list to pass into a C function?

Tags: python, cython, ctypes

I have written a C function named `SortInPlace` which sorts an integer array in place. Now I want to call it from the Python. Following is the core of my code:

```
def sort_in_place(vs):
    buffer = (c_void_p * len(vs))(*vs)
    lib.SortInPlace.argtypes = [c_void_p]
    lib.SortInPlace.restype = None
    lib.SortInPlace(buffer)
    print "buffer: ", buffer

vs = [3,2,1]
sort_in_place(vs)
print "vs: ", vs
```

However, the result turns out to be

```
buffer: 1,2,3
vs: 3,2,1
```

I printed the **address** of `buffer` and `vs`, which show that **they have difference memory addresses**. Thus, `buffer` is sorted in place, but `vs` is untouched.

I also tried to use `array` to convert `vs` to a pointer by:

```
from array import array
a = array('l',vs)

# however, their addresses are also different
print hex(id(vs))
print hex(a.buffer_info()[0])
```

In both case, the original `vs` is always **copied** to a new memory buffer. My question is: **how can I directly create a buffer from the address of a Python list object without copying?**

Comment: You cannot. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/47008303/5769463 for how such cases can be handled. Because the data in a list is not a continuous array of int-values.

Comment: `buffer = (c_void_p * len(vs))(*vs)` seams to copy the data. Can you write values back to `vs` after calling `lib.SortInPlace(buffer)` ? Would be a workaround.

Comment: @rocksportrocker that is what I am expecting to avoid, since it may be inefficient.

Comment: @ead I see. That is sooooooooo sad...

Comment: You could almost certainly get a ctypes pointer from an array (not a list) and then modify the data in that array